# Using lm() in R in data with many zeroes gives error

Tags: r, modeling, linear-regression, data-analysis

I'm new to data analysis, and I have a couple questions about using lm() in R to create a linear regression model of my data.

My data looks like this:

```
testID    userID    timeSpentStudying    testGrade
12345     007       10                   90
09876     008       0                    75
```

And my model:

```
model <- lm(formula = data$testGrade ~ timeSpentStudying, data = data)
```

I'm getting the following error (twice), across just under 60 rows of data from RStudio:

```
Warning messages:
1: In sqrt(crit * p * (1 - hh)/hh) : NaNs produced
2: In sqrt(crit * p * (1 - hh)/hh) : NaNs produced
```

My question is, does the problem have to do with the data containing many instances of zero being the value, such as above under the 'timeSpentStudying' column? If so, how do I handle that? Shouldn't lm() be able to handle values of zero, especially if that would give significance to the data itself?

Thanks!

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7919/how-are-zero-values-handled-in-lm

Comment: It should still run with lots of zeros but it'll probably fail the assumption that residuals are normally distributed, you'll need to run a zero-inflated regression model. Zeros shouldn't stop it running though, what does `str(data)` look like?

Comment: FYI: These are not errors, they are warnings. It doesn't mean you should ignore them, but there are differences.

Comment: Did you log anything?

Comment: You could edit your question with the result of `dput(your_data)`to provide us with your data. This way we can replicate your warning and see what is causing it.

Comment: As an aside, when you use the data argument `data = data`, you don't have to repeat the data frame name in the formula `data$testGrade ~ ...`.

Comment: And, given that the zeros are in a predictor, not the response, a zero-inflated model is **not** appropriate.

Comment: @Gregor so would using a zero-inflated poisson regression not be advisable here? It seems like that would make sense given the abundance of zeros in the data

Comment: No.  As @Gregor already pointed out, zero-inflation is for cases where there are lots of zeros in the **response** variable.

Answer (score 0):

So far I have been unable to replicate this, e.g.:

```
dd <- data.frame(y=rnorm(1000),x=c(rep(0,990),1:10))
model <- lm(y~x, data = dd)
summary(model)
```

[Searching the R code base for the code listed in your error](https://github.com/wch/r-source/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sqrt%28crit+*+p+*+%281+-+hh%29%2Fhh%29) and tracing back indicates that the relevant lines are in `plot.lm`, the function that plots diagnostics, and that the problem is that you are somehow getting a value >1 for the leverage or "hat values" of one of your data points.  However, I can't see how you could be achieving that.  Data would make this much clearer!